# How to automate tasks for non-techies like customer support?

Tags: scripting, automation

Our Customer Support often needs small changes to our system. These are things that a dev does by running a tiny script, but that's out-of-reach for CS. I'd like to be able to make those scripts accessible in a safe way. Basically, a list of commands to click on, and for parameters you'd usually choose a value out of a dynamically created list.

Jenkins and Rundeck seem *very* overblown for exposing a bunch of shell scripts via tests, but I can't seem to find something tiny. Also, Jenkins does not seem to be restrictive enough: I'd really have to control the possible inputs rigorously. (Not to avoid errors, the scripts can verify input, but to actually make CS self-sufficient.)

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem? Build a tiny app? :/

Comment: Rundeck seems about right. I'm not sure why you think it's overblown.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHampton and use Rundeck for this. It may be a Java app, but it's easy to run and actually rather lightweight. Plus there's a bunch of plugins to integrate with whatever other tools your using (see http://rundeck.org/plugins/index.html).

Comment: I don't need the node concept, and wouldn't want the users to be confused by it. Running freetext commands is a no-no. Generally, the big question in regards to Rundeck is, if I can dumb it down enough to be useful for my purpose. I guess, I'll play around and make it work. Thanks for the recommendation!